# When servers need a SSH tunnel (VPN tunnel) to internal network resources, are they permanent connections?

Tags: vpn

So I just want to understand the concept for a vpn tunnel (ssh tunnel) connection for servers from another company coming into our company network.  Is this vpn tunnel persistent or does the connection disconnect when not in use?  I am comparing it to my own experience with vpn-ing into my company to access resources, and I disconnect when i'm done.  Is this the same for servers that need to constantly poll systems in another corporate network, in that it just stays on all the time until you disconnect, or is this a different type of vpn where it stays on all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario you need a Point-to-point VPN tunnel with IPSec where servers in Site-A will be able to connect to servers in Site-B permanently. In fact you are connecting two networks for example 192.168.10.0/24 connected to 10.128.0.0/20. For this to work you will need a VPN Device in both sides to establish the tunnel. Usually an IPSec capable firewall or router appliance. You could even use a server to host the VPN software (such as Strongswan) but the configuration is a bit complicated.

Unrelated : 
The scenario you are used to is called Remote Access VPN, or Road Warrior VPN.
Additionally, an SSH Tunnel is also unrelated because it only uses SSH encryption and not a real VPN Tunnel.

You will find plenty of examples if you Google 'IPSec'. I recommend reading this [article](https://www.lifewire.com/vpns-ipsec-vs-ssl-2486720) for more information.

Comment: thanks that makes sense.  I asked one of the network guys and you pretty much confirmed it.  Going back to your scenario where we are establishing a site to site vpn with site A.  We need to push some files over to their ftp server.   Our admin wanted to know if their ftp is internal to their network.  And they said it is not internal to the vpn and is going external.  Does that mean the ftp server is in their dmz and would not need to be configured to be within the vpn?  I verified that it has a public ip.

Comment: If it has a public IP you don't need to include it in the VPN's traffic. Unless there's a specific reason (ie. Encryption or whitelisting). If you end-up including it you will need their admin to give you  its private IP.